# Wicket form with list of all available values

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

Suppose we have following entities (representing a m:n relation, with additional column on the join table):

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private List<Login> logins;
}

public class Login {
   private User user;
   private Website website;
   private String login;
}

public class Website {
   private String name;
   private List<Login> logins;
}
```

I want to create a `User` edit form that contains one login input field per each existing website (so that all existing websites are in the form). E.g., having 2 websites defined (website1, website2), I would like to see:

[image: form]

My problem is with achieving following behavior on submission of the form: if login input field is filled for a website, it should be added to user1's logins, and if it's empty, it should not be added/get removed.

I created the form using `User` model (for user name), and website's fields use `ListView` backed by a model of all logins (taken straight from DB). This makes my form look as expected, but the behaviour is not there, as websites model is independent from the `User` model. What is your recommended approach?

Comment: one login for multiple website right?if it so then you have to change model approach?

Comment: No, that's one login per website.

Comment: for me your model seems to be ok. if you have any issue with coding share it. will sorted out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `ListView` to `PropertyListView` did the trick. Model gets updated properly and therefore I can do any required postprocessing in `onSubmit()`. With the `ListView`, form was rendered fine, but changes in login input fields were ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListView` backed by a list of all possible `Login` objects, ie the existing `Login` object if it exists and a dummy/empty/new `Login` object for each `Website` for which it doesn't exist.

Then on form submission save those `Login` objects which have a not-`null` and not-empty login field.

You could create a bean instead of directly using the `Login` object but it would work the same way.

If you also want to delete `Login` objects for which the user removed the login value, create some way in which you can check the `Login` object has been saved before (ie, its `login` field was notempty once) and delete the object if it is empty now.

Comment: Hi, of course I use the ListView as suggested (updated my question). The problem is that in onSubmit() i can't see updated Login values from the input fields (User's name is updated fine).

Comment: Ah, then you clarify your question by describing the problem you're having. Your question as it currently stands asks for a recommended approach in general, not for help solving that specific problem.

Is the listview part of the form?